# AutoStart Kodi app on Android

Tags: java, android, center, media, kodi

I've a small box that run Android. I want to use it like a media center, so I would install Kodi, but I want Kodi to autostart at boot.

Have I to modify Kodi App? Android System? In which way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: It's not a problem...

Answer (score 1):

On Kodi's website they recommend to use [this startup manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.startupmanager) to do so. Here's the [link](http://kodi.wiki/view/Android_FAQ#Automatically_start_Kodi) to this recommendation.